# Avoid double border size with :hover pseudo-class of child element

Tags: html, css

I've made a `<ul>`, whose `<li>`-elements have no borders. If a `<li>` is hovered, it gets a 3px black border, and if a `<li>` is clicked it becomes a `<span>`-child of the selected `<li>`.

Unfortunately, if I hover this `<span>`, an additional 3px border is added so a border of 6px in total is shown.

How can I avoid this?

Is there a way to disable the `li:hover` effect on children of the `li`?

My code:

```
.tablinks li {
    color: #8c8c8e;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.tablinks span {
    display: block;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-width:3px;
    color:#000;
}

.tablinks > li:hover {
    color: #000;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-width:3px;
}
```

I already tried to set the border-width of  `span:hover` to 0px. Unfortunately the border will jump to 0px and then jump to 3px which looks horrible (caused by the transition I think):

```
.tablinks span:hover {
    border-width:0px;
}
```

Comment: remove `border-width:0px;` inside the hover.

Comment: Then the border will be 6px instead of 3px while hovering.

Comment: I don't see 6px anywhere, can you post a fiddle?

Comment: What is the markup? `ul > li > span`? If so, just add `.tablinks li:hover span { border:none; }`

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do, i tried to replicate it but I'm just unclear.  http://jsfiddle.net/WQ8r8/

Comment: @DanielAsking: `Is there a way to disable the li:hover effect on children of the li?` The hover effect is only ever applied to the `li` and not it's children. Your `span` adds 3px to it's border, while the outer `li` adds 3px to it's border from the `hover`. You need to either set the `span`'s parent, the `li`, to a fixed 3px instead of the `span` or tell `hover` to exclude certain `li` elements. The only way to currently achieve this until CSS4 `parent selectors` become reality would be using the `not` selector. Sadly `not` does not allow child selectors inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to add to the code which injects the `span` tag, you could add a class to the `li` element which you have selected.

That would allow you to use the `:not` selector to exclude the selected element, similar to this:

```
.tablinks > li:not(.selected):hover{
   color: #000;
   border-top-color: #000;
   border-top-style: solid;
   border-width:3px;
}
```

Say you have this default HTML:

```
<ul class="tablinks">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

After one item has been selected you end up with this:

```
<ul class="tablinks">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li class="selected"><span>item 2</span></li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Using the mentioned CSS changes would exclude the selected `li`.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kny8f/) - Excluding selected `li`

---

It doesn't have to be a class it could also be a data attribute, similar to this:

```
<ul class="tablinks">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li data-selected><span>item 2</span></li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Then change the CSS to something similar to this:

```
.tablinks > li:not([data-selected]):hover{
    color: #000;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-width:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.tablinks li span { border-width: 0px; }
```

You will delete the .tablinks span { border-width } class that affect the border-width of the "li span"

with .tablinks span you'll affect the span child of li element, so when you go hover the li, it takes 3px (".tablinks > li:hover" said) and also ".tablinks span" set 3px under the li element.

You can also change ".tablinks span" to

```
.tablinks > span
```

if your span is already direct of .tablinks

Comment: `.tablinks li span { border-width: 0px; }` removes the border from the `span` all together [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F37yP/). From the CSS in the question I would have assumed the border on the `span` is intentionally to visually indicate an `li` has been selected. So I'd assume removing it is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that instead of the last block you posted :

```
.tablinks li:hover span {
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This causes a very visible flicker as the border of the `span` is removed while the border of the outer `li` is added. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztY53/) assuming OPs HTML is as in the fiddle. Which I assume so going by the provided CSS from the OP.